# problem using content observer to update call log

Tags: android

i have a `fragment` and i read call log and show in `recyclerview` inside it.
i use content observer to apply call log updates.

problem is content observers on change method isn't called on outgoing calls and just is called on incoming and missed calls.
please help about problem also show me best way to update call log and show it inside `recyclerview`.
here is my content observer class and how i register and unregistere it

```
public class CallLogChangeObserverClass extends ContentObserver
{
    public CallLogChangeObserverClass(Handler handler, Context ct) {
        super(handler);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "call log changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Here I register content observer

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity()
        .getContentResolver()
        .registerContentObserver(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, true, callLogchangeevents);
}
```

and unregister :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity()
        .getContentResolver()
        .unregisterContentObserver(callLogchangeevents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved. just in case for somebody face same problem, problem was that I was unregistering observer inside onPause() method, so when making call before observer can detect the log change, got  unregistered . I moved the unregister method to on detach method of fragment and problem solved.